# Cannot 'getObject' from lambda on s3 bucket when the object is created by another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have 3 accounts I will refer to as account AA, BB and CC.

AA does a putObject to a s3 bucket in BB, and CC has a lambda that is triggered when an object is created in BB

When I create an object in the s3 bucket from account BB, the lambda works as expected. I can do this through the console, or the s3 api.

When the object is put in there from account AA, I am able to read the event in the lambda, but get `Access Denied` when trying to do an `s3:GetObject`

At one point I had the lambda in BB, and it was able to perform the `s3:GetObject` on objects created by AA. It is only when I moved the lambda to CC, did i start experiencing issues with objects created by AA.

here is my s3 bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AA:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::CC:role/LAMBDA_ARN"
            },
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my statement from CC lambda that allows access to the s3

```
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME*/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
        }
```

The lambda execution role has full permissions to `s3:get*` on account BB.

The fact that it was written by another account should not affect reading that object, As I can take that same object that was written in there from AA, write it into BB again, and CC lambda will be able to read it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When writing an object to Amazon S3 from a different account (that is, from an account that does not own the S3 bucket), it is recommended to **set the ACL** to `bucket-owner-full-control`. This allows the bucket owner to control the object.

As strange as it seems, it is possible to create objects in a bucket that the owning account cannot access!

See: [Access Control List (ACL) Overview - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl)